# Getting error while trying to create Python 3 virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have Python 2.7 as default however I also have Python 3.5 installed separately

```
 virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.5 kivyPy3.5
```

I am trying to setup Python 3.5 virtual env for kivy app development but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/enum/__init__.py", line 371, in __getattr__
    return cls._member_map_[name]
KeyError: '_convert'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 23, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 364, in <module>
    import signal
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/signal.py", line 8, in <module>
    _IntEnum._convert(
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/enum/__init__.py", line 373, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: _convert
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Did you python3.5 path correct? `/usr/local/bin/python3.5`?

Comment: why are you using a development version of python?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham right, I actually was trying but I think even kivy has got incompatibility for which i was setting up the env.

Answer (score 0):

```
Installation:
step 1:
>> sudo easy_install virtualenv

step 2:
Creating the First Virtual Environment

>> mkdir first_evn

>> virtualenv first_env/test_env
or
>> virtualenv first_env/test_env --no-site-packages

-no-site-packages:  If you don’t want to use any preinstalled packages from my operating system

step 3: activating environment

>> source /first_env/test_env/bin/activate

step 4: Deactivating Environment

>> deactivate

Important: if you  have more than one versions of Python on your server or local system and you want to create a viertualenv for a specific version of python then please replace the step 2 with following 

For Ubuntu
>>  virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.3 first_env/test_env

For Window

>> virtualenv --python=c:\Python33\python.exe first_env/test_env

For mac
virtualenv --python=python3.4 test_env

Adding virtual env path in .base_profile file

>>> pico ~/.bash_profile

And add live alias ff='source ~/PATH_FROM_ROOT/VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME/bin/activate'
```

Comment: I later used pyenv3.5 to create virtual environment.

Comment: @san which operating system you are using?

Comment: I am on OSx mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the version of the package enum34 that is installed in your system Python 2.7 interacting with the Python 3.5 you are attempting to use for the virtualenv.

To fix it, do the following **using the instance of `pip` associated with your system Python 2.7**.

```
pip install --upgrade enum34
```

Here's a Github issue conversation about it. https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/763